# unable to add a primary key to MS Access table

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to make the "BRFID" field the primary key in this table but I get the following error. (see screenshot). I don't see any other indexed field in the table. I am new to access, what am I doing wrong?
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvCQC.jpg)

Comment: When a message box tells you you can't do something, and includes the reason why, why do you not read that rather than post a screenshot to the Internet asking other people to read it to you?

Comment: Like I said being new to access and it saying that duplicate values would be created in the index,primary key or relationship..I didn't think that meant that making this field a primary key field meant that " there are duplicates in the field itself" especially since its an "auto number" data type..I didnt even think duplicates were even possible in the field.. like I said... new to Access.

Answer (score 1):

A primary key cannot have any duplicate values. Your problem is that there are duplicates entries in the BRFID field. You need to correct that and make every value in that field unique before it can be a Primary Key field.

In the Query Wizard, there is a way to generate a query that identifies duplicate values. Use that to find the duplicates. You'll have to come up with the way to correct the problem.

Comment: I am looking at the field and it has over 5,000 records.. what is the easiest and quickest way to find duplicates? the filter drop down is blank.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that you can use the Query Wizard.